# C++ Global Namespace in a project

Tags: c++, namespaces

I have multiple C++ classes in a Pacman Game project (Maze, Food, Pacman, ...). I made a namespace 'Pacman_AI' so that the classes can be seen every where in the project. However, I got an error for 'GameObject' class: "name followed by '::' must be a class or namespace name".

Here is my "GameObject.cpp" in which I get the error above:

```
namespace Pacman_AI{

vector <pair <int, int> > GameObject::getPoints(){
    return points;
}

string GameObject::getType(){
    return type;
}

}
```

I already defined my "GameObject" class in a different file "GameObject.h".

Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you include the header file where you declared `GameObject`

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: No but could you explain why should I include my header file? I have a global namespace already.

Comment: @MahmoudArafa Source code files in a c++ project are not implicitly aware of each other or of each other's content. You must use [`#include`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/include) to specify, in each file, what headers it relies on. Namespaces cannot fulfill this function.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing is to use `namespace` in your header files

```
// Foo.h
namespace Pacman_AI{

// STUFF HERE

};
```

and then `using namespace` in your .cpp files

```
//Foo.cpp
#include "Foo.h"

using namespace Pacman_AI;

// define your functions here
```

Comment: But I could remove my namespace from "Foo.h" and it will work the same as yours.

Comment: I used namespaces so that I can escape from these "includes". You know like C# namespaces.

Comment: @MahmoudArafa you cannot 'escape' from includes.. and why would you try to do that anyway ?

Comment: @MahmoudArafa c++ includes and c++ namespaces preform different functions and one cannot be used as a substitute for the other. Perhaps [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264249/how-does-the-compilation-linking-process-work) would be of interest to you.

Comment: @All OK it seems like I have to read about namespaces. I just wanted it to work easier like C# namespaces, where every class is shared globally in the project.